# Finding difference within same table

Tags: sql, join, compare

I am trying to find difference in table depending on specific column.

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
+------------------------+
| rn | P_id   | D_id     |
+------------------------+
| 1  | 8      | 20       |
+----+--------------+----+
| 2  | 13     | 20       |
+----+--------------+----+
| 3  | 8      | 21       |
+----+--------------+----+
| 4  | 13     | 21       |
+----+--------------+----+
| 5  | 15     | 21       |
+----+--------------+----+
| 6  | 17     | 21       |
+------------------------+
```

So , I want to get the **P_id** of rows where **D_id** is equal to 21 and is unique (For unique I mean there shouldn't be a row with with same **P_id** where **D_id** is equal to 20)

For example , in the shown table , expected result will be - **P_id** 15 and 17.

Would like get this result using **JOIN** if possible.

**EDIT** : I am using MSSQL . I want to explain the situation just to clarify some confusion . Imagine D_id represents downloadID (21 - latest download , 20 - old one ) , so I want to simply compare data from old download to new one and see if any new data has been added.
In this case those new ones are records where P_id is 15 and 17

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What would happen if you added a row with D_id = 22?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(RN,P_ID,D_ID) AS
(
  SELECT 1 ,  8 ,      20 UNION ALL      
  SELECT 2 ,  13 ,     20   UNION ALL       
  SELECT 3 ,  8  ,     21 UNION ALL         
  SELECT 4  , 13  ,    21 UNION ALL         
  SELECT 5   ,15 ,     21 UNION ALL         
  SELECT  6  , 17,      21      
)
SELECT C.P_ID 
FROM CTE AS C
GROUP BY C.P_ID
HAVING MAX(C.D_ID)=MIN(C.D_ID) AND MAX(C.D_ID)=21
```

Comment: Note that SELECT without a FROM clause is a non-standard syntax, and not supported by all dbms's.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a join, you should use a subquery in which you fetch the number of occurences of a P_id.

This query fetches the number of occurences:

```
SELECT `P_id`, COUNT(`rn`) AS `cnt`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `P_id`;
```

That would mean that the entire query becomes something like this:

```
SELECT t.`P_id`
FROM `table` t
INNER JOIN ( SELECT `P_id`, COUNT(`rn`) AS `cnt`
             FROM `table`
             GROUP BY `P_id` ) c
ON c.`P_id` = t.`P_id`
WHERE t.`D_id` = 21 AND c.`cnt` = 1;
```